# Can't see my databases in OpenERP

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, odoo

I installed openerp 7 on ubuntu and worked for a while.
When I restarted ubuntu, I opened openerp and tried to login but didn't find the databases I've created before and it took me to the (Database Management) page in order to create a new database as if it were my first time.

I tried to make a duplicate of an existing database as a workaround, but when I wrote the old database name, I got this message:

> ProgrammingError: permission denied to copy database "test"

I tried to access postgres using pgadmin and I succeeded and could access all the databases from the pgadmin.

Comment: Have you checked the database permission/owner?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the access rights on particular database for particular openerp user.
First Create the OpenERP user that will own and run the application

```
sudo adduser --system --home=/opt/openerp --group openerp
```

Then Next,

First change to the postgres user so we have the necessary privileges to configure the database.

```
sudo su - postgres
```

Now create a new database user. This is so OpenERP has access rights to connect to PostgreSQL and to create and drop databases. Remember what your choice of password is here; you will need it later on:

```
createuser --createdb --username postgres --no-createrole --no-superuser --pwprompt openerp
Enter password for new role: ********
Enter it again: ********
```

Finally exit from the postgres user account:

```
exit
```

Here is source link http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2012/12/how-to-install-openerp-7-0-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Comment: Thanks dhana, but I already did this during the installation of openerp. When I tried to do this again, I got error messages telling that the user and the role already exist.

Comment: NO, the problem is not solved, I tried to do as your reply but I got errors because the user and role already exist for I did all those steps during the installation already. It was working fine until I restarted ubuntu, I couldn't see the databases since then. What's interesting is that I can access pgadmin and see everything.

Comment: try `sudo -u postgres psql` and `GRANT ALL ON db TO postgres;`